# Is LoaderManager class in Android deprecated for API 30?

Tags: java, android

I'm relatively new to Android development and learning from Udacity. In the course they are using the `LoaderManager` class which I found difficult to understand so I went to the docs where I found that the class is deprecated, but its can still be used from AndroidX. I then went there which told that support for this class is not available. I'm pretty much confused as to whether the class is deprecated or not. If not, can someone suggest some good documentation to learn about using `LoaderManager`?

Comment: The word is "deprecated".  Not "depricated" or "depriciated" or "depreciated" or "depilated".  :-)

Comment: Yes, Loaders are deprecated as a concept

Comment: (And if anyone else gets this wrong, they might be defenestrated :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Mostly documentation from [developer](https://developer.android.com/docs) site and quick documentation of Android Studio will answer most of your quesitons/problems. For example when I was learning SQLite i learnt also using `LoaderManager`. After some times I decided to use SQLite for an app with `LoaderManager` but as you already mentioned it's deprecated (`android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.getSupportLoaderManager()`).

So I looked on quick documentation and found my answer with in seconds. If you call that method and move your mouse on it, Android Studio shows quick documentation (if you enabled quick documentation) and guides you. So according to quick documentation that method is deprecated and it suggests: use `LoaderManager.getInstance(this)`.

In brief documentation from developer site, quick documentation of Android Studio and this site can answer all your questions. If you're learning new things I suggest read also developer's documentation and read quick documentation while practicing because other sources (like Udacity or videos) may not be detailed or may not be up to date.